# <zqu:SelectProduct options="{!theOptions}" /> not working

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, visualforce-component

I am following zuora's instructions, which say to use the following:
`<zqu:SelectProduct options="{!theOptions}" />` when using their SelectProducts custom component.  The problem, is when I add the line:
`<zqu:SelectProduct options="{!theOptions}" />` to the page, it errors out saying: `The installed managed class zqu.ProductSelectorController is not visible.`  The only assumption I am able to make is that somewhere that Controller is being referenced via theOptions, and, the class is not global, but, I am not referencing it anywhere myself, how do I find and remove the reference.  Here is the VF markup:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" tabStyle="zqu__Quote__c" standardController="zqu__Quote__c" extensions="NewMarksCustomPageController">
  <apex:composition template="zqu__QuoteWizardTemplateNoForm" >
     <apex:define name="PageBody" >
      <apex:form >

             <zqu:SelectProduct options="{!theOptions}" />

      </apex:form>
    </apex:define> 
  </apex:composition>  
</apex:page>
```

and here is the class:

```
public with sharing class NewMarksCustomPageController {
  private String quoteId;
//public List<String> fields = new List<String> {'mode'};

  public zqu.SelectProductComponentOptions theOptions { get; set; }    
  public NewMarksCustomPageController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
     theOptions = new zqu.SelectProductComponentOptions();
     quoteId = controller.getId();
     theOptions.title = 'Sample Code';
     theOptions.subTitle = 'Choose Product and Charges';
     theOptions.mode = zqu.SelectProductComponentOptions.MODE_EDIT;

     system.debug('the options title = ' + theOptions.title);
     system.debug('the options first call 1: ' + theOptions);
     system.debug('quote id ' + quoteId);
     //system.debug('list[0] = ' + fields[0]);
     // controller.addFields(fields[0]);
     //  system.debug('added field fields.mode' + fields[0]);

     //   if(theOptions == Null){
     //system.debug('theOptions2 = ' + theOptions);
     //    theOptions = new zqu.SelectProductComponentOptions();


    // }
    //system.debug('theOptions3 = ' + theOptions);
    }

}
```

I have tried removing everything from the vf page except the page tag using an empty constructor and slowly line by line, adding everything back, and, everything stops working as soon as I re-add that line to the vf page

Comment: The component `zqu:SelectProduct` has its own controller `zqu.ProductSelectorController` which for some reason, is not visible to your org

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, but, what do I do to fix it, is this something where I need to contact the client and get them to make it visible or something like that, forgive me, I am a newbie, and, this problem has been a real pain because I can't see that I am doing anything wrong.  Thanks - Mark

Comment: regrettably, I have no specific experience with zuora but I would review the package install guide and make sure that the package's classes and pages have been made visible to the running user's profiles

Comment: OK, I will try that, thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 0):

Its a long shot, but check the package version on the controller page and make sure it is up to date.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexClass xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>23.0</apiVersion>
    <packageVersions>
        <majorNumber>5</majorNumber>
        <minorNumber>90</minorNumber>
        <namespace>zqu</namespace>
   </packageVersions>
<status>Active</status>
```